# Is there any way to display time in format ot hh:mm

Tags: sql, sql-server

i declare table like this

```
create table CHUYENBAY(
    MACB char(4), 
    SBDI char(3), 
    SBDEN char(3), 
    GIODI time(0), 
    GIODEN time(0), 
    primary key (MACB)
)
```

I insert into table

```
insert into CHUYENBAY
    values ('100', 'SLC', 'BOS', '8:00', '17:50')
go
```

i check for its display and it was like this

[image]

is there any way to transform the hh:mm:ss format into hh:mm only, many thanks

Comment: SQL Server does not "display" anything; any value that is not a string stored in your database is a binary value that is generally unreadable to a person. What you see is a function of the tool you are using to view the resultset. Presumably this is SSMS but the same concept applies to whatever development tool/language you eventually use to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Agree with @SMor, Column type is `time`. It is not stored as a `string` . It should not be.
And it is not **Sql Server's** responsibility to render the output. The output in your case is rendered by your client in this case it is SSMS I guess. If you need it to look different do the transformation during the fetch. Refs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this when you retrieve the data, say by using `format()`:

```
select format(GIODI, 'HH:mm')
```

You can also add computed columns to facilitate this for anyone querying the table:

```
alter table CHUYENBAY add column giodi_hhmm as (format(GIODI, 'HH:mm'));
```

Instead of `format()`, you can also use `convert(varchar(5), GIODI, 108)`, so:

```
alter table CHUYENBAY add column giodi_hhmm as (convert(varchar(5), GIODI, 108));
```

Comment: i cannot use the format() function, it hadn't been declare yet, i don't know  if because of my version of sql server is 2008 or not, but i can't use it, so by the way thank for spending your time on me

Comment: @huytrần . . . All supported versions of SQL Server have `format()`.  However, I updated the answer with an alternative (that is probably faster than `format()` as well).

Answer (score 1):

Since you said `format()` was not available, you can use [`convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead:

```
select MACB,
       SBDI,
       SBDEN,
       GIODI  = convert(char(5), GIODI , 108),
       GIODEN = convert(char(5), GIODEN, 108)
from   CHUYENBAY
```

But be aware that if you don't have `format()` then your version of SQL is no longer supported. Time for an upgrade :)

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). You can simply do `convert(char(5), GIODI, 108)` - there's no point of using varchar when the length is known in advance, and there's absolutely no point of using `left` on a `varchar(30)` when you can simply use `char(5)` to begin with.

Comment: Very good point. Force of habit with convert from times long passed. Fixed

Comment: i decide to use this old one to synchronize with my lecturer's version, i am under pressure of getting good grade from university ya know, so thank for helping me :>